# Problem with union the table which not exists

Tags: mysql

I want to get data from several tables which has the same column name in one SQL statement, for example:

`SELECT name, age FROM table_a UNION SELECT name, age FROM table_b UNION...`

But the table_x may not exists that I can't avoid from people who send the request to me, if one of the tables is not exits in a query it will be failed, is there any syntax to avoid that?

I know a way that I can use `show tables` to get all tables in the database and compare them to the request parameters first, but I hope I can do it from MySQL syntax.

Comment: You may have a way if you have a reference table that store all the `Name` data then do a `left join` with `table_a` query and then union it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  If you are using another language in front of it, such PHP or any other language really, you can query the tables as you suggest, but SQL expects the query to be accurate syntactically and if it's not it will error.  There is one (IMO bad) way to do this, if you must.  You could use a stored procedure, which would allow you to dynamically build the query as you would in PHP or another language, but that's about all you have with MySQL (or any database that I know).